# React Native upload image with axios and expo image picker

Tags: react-native, image, axios, upload, expo-image-picker

i'm trying to upload a image with expo image picker and axios.

It's my code:

```js
// Select image from Library <--comment
  const selectImage = async () => {
    // Get iamge
    try {
      // Check has library permission <--comment
      const hasLibraryPermission = await requestLibraryPermision();
      if (hasLibraryPermission) {
        // Lunch camers <--comment
        const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync();

        // Check is canceld or not <--comment
        if (!result.canceled) {
          // Set result uri to state <--comment
          const newInformation = { ...information };
          newInformation.data.image = result.assets[0].uri;
          setInformation(newInformation);

          // Define and append result to form data <--comment
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append("image", result.assets[0]);

          // Define request url <--comment
          const url = `${serverData.url}/profile/update-image`;

          // Send post upload image request <--comment
          await axios
            .post(url, formData, {
              headers: {
                "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
              },
            })
            .then((response) => {
              console.log("response: ", response.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log("CATCH ERROR: ", error);
            });
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error: ", error);
    }
  };
```

The request show this error log: `CATCH ERROR:  [AxiosError: Network Error]`
I searched in the web and even ask at the bard and chat gpt ai's but they can't answer me, whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

A file object should have `uri`, `name` and `type` fields, something like this:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append(
  'image',
  {
    uri: result.assets[0].uri,
    name: <name>,
    type: <type>
  }
);
axios.post(<url>, formData);
```

Comment: I tried this, but the request responsed me `CATCH ERROR:  [AxiosError: Network Error]`.
The error did not change

Comment: This is my result log: `{"assetId": null, "base64": null, "duration": null, "exif": null, "height": 4032, "rotation": null, "type": "image", "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540miladpegah%252Fcilivo-demo/ImagePicker/f355256e-abeb-4198-8afc-a875e5ab9ae8.jpeg", "width": 3024}`

Comment: Looks fine to me. Are you sure your server can be reached from the application?

Comment: Yes server is reached fine, and other parts are work fine but just this request is the problem

Comment: Look, when i send you object to the server, axios return me network error and the problem is file object

Comment: This works for me, so without the server I cannot help you.

Comment: Tank you so much, the server wort with php lument and just returns is it file or not.
If you have an idea, i can connect to you out of stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem with very similar symptoms and thought it was a client side issue, but in the end I realized I had misconfigured my Django server. As the other poster said, if the form data contains that data then the server should be able to parse it if configured correctly. If you happen to be using a Django server then it should look something like this:

```
class UploadImageView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser,)

  def post(self, request):
    try:
        image = request.data["image"]
        print("successfully uploaded it")
    except:
        print("Didnt do it")
```

Comment: tank's charlie, i'm using php server

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `AllowsEditing: true` in your `ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync` ?

I had the same error and i fixed it by:

**1 -** Seting `AllowsEditing: false`

**2 -** Instead of using `axios` or `fetch` to send request i used `FileSystem.uploadAsync` in `expo-file-system`